# Ghostscript v9.0 force font recognition

Tags: windows-7, font, ghostscript

How can I get ghostscript v9.0 running on a windows 7 server to recognize a local font as the one it has embedded?  I'm trying to convert a pdf with an embedded AkzidenzGroteskBE font and want it to use a AkzidGroCFFReg.otf open type font when rendering.

When I run it with -dFAPIDEBUG it says:

```
FAPIhook DRWIBO+AkzidenzGroteskBE-LightCN
Trying to render the Font DRWIBO_AkzidenzGroteskBE-LightCn with FAPI...
Font DRWIBO+AkzidenzGroteskBE-LightCn is being rendered with FAPI=FreeType
FAPIhook --nostringval--
Font --nostringval -- (aliased from DRWIBO+AkzidenzGroteskBE-LightCn) is mapped to FAPI=FreeType
```

The command I'm using to run it is:

`gs9.00\bin\gswin32.exe -dFAPIDEBUG -Ic:\TEMP\font -SDEVICE=pngalpha -r300 -sOuputFile=test.png inputFile.pdf`

I have AkzidGroCFFReg.otf as well as the rest of the family of fonts in the c:\TEMP\font directory (they are also installed on the system).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If a font is embedded in the PDF itself, then all PDF renderers are supposed to use **that** one, not any locally installed font.

If you want to ***replace*** the embedded font, you'll not get that for free (as in beer) or in an easily achieved way.

There is (rather expensive) payware that is able to un-embed embedded fonts from a PDF. (At least there is no (reliably working) Free (as in liberty) software that can do it...

One (rather tedious, error-prone and difficult difficult) method would be to convert the PDF to PostScript, open the .ps file in an editor, remove the font(s), save the file and re-convert the .ps to a PDF again (using an Ghostscript commandline). Or directly from .ps to the PNG you want without the detour via PDF... But this method requires you to know quite a bit about the PostScript language.

Comment: I would suggest that this really only requires a passing familiarity with the structure of postscript documents, rather than "quite a bit about postscript".  That is, I think it is generally easy to remove resources from a postscript document if the postscript generator follows the document structuring conventions, because the comments make it easy to identify the embedded resources.